# How to download a non-dependency artefact as part of buildScript block for Semantic Versioning

Tags: gradle, ivy, semantic-versioning

First off, I have no code to show since I'm completely stumped with this one. This is bad form for an SO question so I really do apologize - I worked entire yesterday on the related build script but couldn't get anything useful to show for this.

I am currently working on a build script that as part of the `jar` task *(or rather its `doLast {}` closure)* would verify the current JAR against previous published JAR from my own Artifactory using the [SemVer API](https://github.com/jeluard/semantic-versioning). Everything else that I have works except for actually downloading the previous version of the project; I can't seem to be able to devise a working script.

My approach so far was based on the reasoning that as Gradle uses Ivy as its dependency management system I should be able to just call some of [Ivy's Ant tasks](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ant.html) with the right parameters - the same as current project so I actually have access to group, name and current version easily - and then get the path to downloaded artefact file and use it as input for the aforementioned SemVer API. Being a bit of Gradle newbie and not actually have used Ivy for a few years even my struggle revealed to me that at this point I have no idea how to really do this in a clean way. One of my major hurdles with this has also so far been that Gradle's documentation is too extensive making it difficult to find things when I don't even remember the right terms for certain bits I want to have.

As I'm not providing any code/build script samples of what I have so far, I don't mind if your answers are just nudges to right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle has not used Ivy internally for some time, so I doubt very much if your approach of using Ivy ant tasks will work.

I would probably do this in a separate task, rather than add actions to the jar task. There is probably a more elegant way, but you could try something like:

```
configurations { lastPublishedVersion }
configurations.lastPublishedVersion.transitive=false

dependencies {
  lastPublishedVersion group: group, name: name, version: "+"
}

task checkSemVer {
   dependsOn jar
   dependsOn configurations.lastPublishedVersion
   doLast {
     println configurations.lastPublishedVersion.getSingleFile() 
   }

}
```

PS If you get this working it would make for a very interesting gradle plugin if you wanted to release it :)

Comment: @Esko, is that what You're looking for?